# Toggle div as Checkbox with CSS3

Tags: html, css

I was trying to re-design my html checkboxes, but... something goes wrong, probably, and its not really working.
my HTML code is:

```
<div class="checkit">
    <label for="checkbox-1">
        <i class="icon-check"></i>
    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1" />
</div>
```

And The Css3 Code Is:

```
.checkit {
    display:block;
    background:#ffffff;
    border:1px solid #e8e8e8;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
    width:18.9px;
    height:17.8px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.checkit:hover {
    border:1px solid #c0c0c0;
}

.checkit:active {
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 5px #7c7c7c;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 5px #7c7c7c;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 5px #7c7c7c;
}

.checkit i {
    color:#a3ec15;
    font-size:23px;
    position:absolute;
    text-shadow:0px 0px 5px #eaeaea;
    margin:-5px -8.9px;
    display:none;
}

.checkit input[type="checkbox"] {
    visibility:hidden;
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
}

.checkit label {
    cursor:inherit;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.checkit input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label i {
    display:block;
}

.checkit input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label i {
    display:none;
}
```

what i was trying to do is, show a V sign (✔) when the main box (checkit) pressed, and when it's not, then hide (by using display css)
(p.s.: icon-check class is my v sign, using font-icons for the site. because i can't use the font here - there is no where to upload it - i will show with the default check sign in the demo)

here's the jsFiddle link for demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/FatboySlim/urg2mumv/

I'm also considering using javascript toggle instead, but I wanted it to be pure css3

any help would be very appriciated.

thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put the input in the front. Check out the **working snippet** here. Use this way:

```css
.checkit {
  display:block;
  background:#ffffff;
  border:1px solid #e8e8e8;
  -webkit-border-radius:5px;
  -moz-border-radius:5px;
  border-radius:5px;
  width:18.9px;
  height:17.8px;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.checkit:hover {
  border:1px solid #c0c0c0;
}

.checkit:active {
  -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 5px #7c7c7c;
  -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 5px #7c7c7c;
  box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 5px #7c7c7c;
}

.checkit i {
  color:#a3ec15;
  font-size:23px;
  position:absolute;
  text-shadow:0px 0px 5px #eaeaea;
  margin:-5px -8.9px;
  display:none;
}

.checkit input[type="checkbox"] {
  /*visibility:hidden;
  width:0px;
  height:0px;*/
}

.checkit label {
  cursor:inherit;
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

.icon-check:after {
  content:"✔";
  font-family:Arial;
}

.checkit input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label i {
  display:block;
}

.checkit input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label i {
  display:none;
}

.checkit input[type="checkbox"] {display: none;}
```

```html
<div class="checkit">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1" />
  <label for="checkbox-1">
    <i class="icon-check"></i>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Just a small nitpick: the input needs to be in front here only because of the CSS that OP is using. The checkbox (hack) will work with the input after the label as well, if you use appropriate CSS.

Comment: @TylerH Yes I know! `:D`

Comment: does this works with radio buttons too ? thanks again :)